# Missing cursor in form text boxes in Firefox 23

Tags: forms, firefox, cross-browser, css

I have an issue on Firefox where I see no cursor in text boxes in my form. This is seen on Firefox 22 and, since I upgraded this morning, 23.0.1.

This doesn't happen in Chrome or IE and appears to be a Firefox-specific problem, but by removing styles from the form fields in Firebug I can't seem to narrow it down.

One of my form fields:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="CardNum" name="CardNum" class="textbox">
```

The CSS that applies to that form field:

```
.input_box_shadow, .standard_form textarea, .standard_input, .standard_form input {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #EDECEC, #DDDDDD) repeat scroll 0 0 border-box #F4F4F0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px white, 0 0 12px #F4F4F0 inset, -999px 0 0 #F4F4F0 inset;
    outline: medium none;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}
.standard_input, .standard_form input {
    color: #434242;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    height: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 230px;
}
button, input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: a jsfiddle could be useful.

Comment: Just checked the code you posted in Firefox 23.0.1 on Mac and it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have traced this back to my code, with the following being the culprit.

```
$('form').on('focus','li', function(event) {
    if($(this).closest('form').attr('id') == 'oform'){
       return false;
    }
    $(this).closest('form').find('li').css('zIndex', '0');
    $(this).css('zIndex', 1998);
});
```

I changed `return false;` for `event.preventBubble = true;` and this resolved the issue for Firefox.